# How to prevent disposal of a StatefulWidget?

Tags: flutter

Adding conditional constructs in tree building logic results in mounting/unmounting of the widget. Which in turn leads to annoying animation issues if the widget is animated with a controller inside.

How can you tell Flutter to prevent widget state from being disposed, and instead search for it in another part of a tree?

```dart
build(BuildContext context) {
  var value = controller.value;

  /// Let's avoid blinking at high opacity, save CPU at the same time

  /// commenting this line will result in smooth animation
  /// when it is uncommented, Flutter will dispose the State which was previously lying under Opacity() widget  
  if(value >= 0.95) return MyAnimatedWidget();

  return Opacity(
   opacity: value,
   child: MyAnimatedWidget();
  );
}
```

Comment: tried `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`?

Comment: It seem to solve a more difficult task - keep alive widget which is no longer in the tree. Here, the widget stays in the tree under a different node. Also looks like a complex overkill

Comment: is `State.dispose` called when mixing your custom `State` with it?

Comment: @pskink `State.disposed` is called for `MyAnimatedWidget` when opacity reaches 0.95. Framework no longer sees it at a previous place, so it creates a new `State` with no `Opacity`  as a parent. I have a bouncing opacity from 0 to 1 to 0 etc in my test, so animation keeps resetting when opacity is around value 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `MyAnimatedWidget()` in your code, this means that you initiate a new instance of widget again that's why the old one is getting disposed because it isn't used anymore.

You can create a field of type `MyAnimatedWidget()` inside your class and return it with the opacity or not. So I will be only one instance of your widget and I won't get disposed.

```
MyAnimatedWidget animatedWidget = MyAnimatedWidget();

build(BuildContext context) {
  var value = controller.value;

  /// Let's avoid blinking at high opacity, save CPU at the same time

  /// commenting this line will result in smooth animation
  /// when it is uncommented, Flutter will dispose the State which was previously lying under Opacity() widget  
  if(value >= 0.95) return animatedWidget ;

  return Opacity(
   opacity: value,
   child: animatedWidget ;
  );
}
```

Comment: That will unfortunately result in `defunct` state of a `MyAnimatedWidget` after it is disposed. The only way working or us now is by avoiding stateful widgets at all. Introducing custom ticker factories, then passing `Controller` & everything as parameters to a `StatelessWidget` to use inside an `AnimatedBuilder`. Making parent widget responsible for disposal of everything